# A travel time table Database Design

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am working on a travel time table system. A specific destination is to have at least three (3) departure time. These departure time varies based on the  type of day (peak or non-peak). Below is the description of my current design:

**DepartureTable**

## Destination  | time1 | time2 | time3 | day_type

--> the required output is to be displayed in a table like :

```
routeABC | 6:30 | 6:45 | 6:50 | peak
routeABC | 6:40 | 7:00 | 8:45 | non-peak
routeXYZ | 7:00 | 7:30 | 7:40 | peak
```

Please, does it pass the 1NF test (i doubt because of the repeating column name) ?

Comment: From my point of view is not very clear your goal, but I have one general remark - don't design your tables to look exactly like desired result. From my experience this is very bad idea. You have SQL so you can transfer data as you like. Also the display requirement are one today and can be changed tomorrow - you can not change database design each time.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply @BogdanBogdanov. my question is if my current table design is ok ?. with this current design, i get the desired result but the time1, time2.. column seems to be a repeating group stuff. i  am seeking for an alternative proper design suggestion if you think this isn't a good one.

Comment: The design depends of "whole picture". Describe all elements of your database. Think of desired result - what kind of data you will need to store and what results will be required and make design. I can not tell if design is ok or not, because I don't have information about your other data and the rules applied. In general you have a lot of options. You can denormalize tables to show repetitive info if you need speed, or you can expand data required each time to achive more manageble database. Even with specific data that you provide the question is kind a broad one.

Comment: Sir, the database is as simple as the table i just described. the information about route and their departure time is all i want to store. there are no information left out. the program am making is just going to pull this information and display it on a table. it's really not a big project. hope u understand .

Comment: Sorry. In the case you pull data from this table for app with only this table it sound good for me. As I told you in this case you have denormilized table. How many records you will store in this table? In general for so simple app design of not a big issue.

Comment: i might want to store up to a 100 records. but the point of this whole program is for me to practice proper database design. i have read too many books but little practice. so am hoping to learn of good database design techniques through this. I am really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: 100 records is nothing. I think that your database have very simple design. Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Am using SQL SERVER 2008. so you think this design have passed the normalization test ?

Comment: So your actual question is does my design passed normalization test? Edit the question. Use AdventureWorks to see see practical application of design. I think that your table is denormalized - which is the oppozite az normalized table. Also normalization have several levels. You need to reffer which normal form you need to be checked your desing against.

Comment: Ok. i have edited the Question. Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: It looks like (destination, day_type) is a candidate key, if so and if you have exactly 3 times for every route and day_type, then your design is good.  If you have a variable number of times, then I would suggest something like (destination, day_type, ordinal, time) with (destination, day_type, ordinal) as key.

Comment: Thanks@reaanb. i have considered your suggestion. it seems to fit in my situation. but i have an issue. how can i display this information in a tabular form like the one i described in my Question ??

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of an answer then you were hoping for.

Your output

```
routeABC | 6:30 | 6:45 | 6:50 | peak
```

contains more information than you think.

A transportation system consists of Stations, Vehicles, Departure Times, Routes, and Route Departure Times.

### Station

Let's take Stations first.  We'll create a Station table.

```
Station
-------
Station ID
Station Name
Station Address
...
```

Generally, table names are singular.  The Station ID is a meaningless number, usually an auto-incrementing integer, that internally identifies the row in the table.  Another name for this is blind key.  The Station ID is the primary key of the Station table.

All of the information in the Station table pertains to the station.  This is the third normal form.  The shorthand way to see if a table is in third normal form is by asking yourself this question.

> Does the data relate to the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd?

The key is first normal form.

The whole key is second normal form.

Nothing but the key is third normal form.

### Vehicle

Next, we'll look at the Vehicle table.

```
Vehicle
-------
Vehicle ID
Vehicle Type (Bus, Light Rail, Heavy Rail, etc.)
Vehicle VIN
Vehicle License Plate
...
```

The Vehicle ID is the primary key.  It's an auto-incrementing integer.  It can have the same values as the Station ID we talked about earlier.  However, those same values mean different rows in the database.

### Departure Time

Each station has one or more departure times.  In your question, you mentioned 3 departure times.  By normalizing your database, you can allow for more than 3 departure times.

Let's look at the Departure Time table.

```
Departure Time
--------------
Departure Time ID
Departure Time Stamp.
Station ID
```

The primary key is Departure Time ID, an auto-incrementing integer.  The same Station ID can be repeated for different departure time stamps.  This table would also have an index on (Station ID, Departure Time Stamp DESCending).

### Route

We've created three tables, Station, Vehicle, and Departure Time.  These tables are called domain tables, because they describe an object in our domain.  Stations and vehicles are physical objects.  Departure Time isn't physical, but it's still an object.

Let's take a look at a Route table.

```
Route
-----
Route ID
Vehicle ID
Route Type (Peak, Non-peak, etc.)
```

Route ID is the primary key, an auto-incrementing integer.  Vehicle ID is the blind key from the Vehicle table.  Using the blind key, we create a relationship from the Route table to the Vehicle table.

A route has one vehicle.  A route has one type.

### Route Departure Time

A route has one or more Departure Times.

Let's look at a Route Departure Table.

```
Route Departure Table
---------------------
Route ID
Departure Time ID
Departure Time Sequence
```

The primary key is (Route ID, Departure Time Sequence).  We need two columns to create a unique primary key.

The Route ID is the blind key from the Route Table.

The Departure Time ID is the blind key from the Departure Time Table.

The Departure Time Sequence is an integer that when sorted, gives the departure times in order.  This is because a route can run past midnight.

### Conclusion

I hope you don't see this as an over-complicated solution.  The reason we normalize databases is so we don't duplicate the data, and we can mix and match the data to get different outputs.  The schedule for a bus driver looks different and is different than the schedule for a bus rider.

Comment: Thank you sir for your input. i will definitely look into your suggestions when i am ready to go big. For now, i am only making a sort of time table not a full blown transportation system. Once again thank You.